With Sharing and Without Sharing scenario
I have recently started learning about apex security. I have one scenario where I'm not able to tell the exact outcome even after going through a lot of articles and youtube videos.
Scenario: When 'with sharing' class calls method from 'without sharing' class, what is the outcome? Based on the documentation, I understand that it should be 'without sharing' since the method is defined in that class. But I saw some examples where this didn't happen.
Also, when the scenario is reversed, when 'without sharing' class calls method from 'with sharing' class, is the outcome in 'with sharing' context?

Any SOQL queries in a method directly in a with or without sharing class do or do not have sharing applied based on the containing class. It does not matter from where the method is called. The only time the caller is relevant is when using implied or inherited sharing.

The key is that the sharing keyword only relates to database activity. Returning data from a without sharing class method to a with sharing one does not cause any change in the records so passed.

These are basic scenarios which can be tested from a proper test class. Have you tried that?

When Class A declared "with sharing" class calls Class B declared "without sharing", queries in Class B will run without sharing.  Sometimes that's needed.  This is where "inherited sharing" becomes useful.  If you have utility classes that do work for several other classes, it may be best to declare them "inherited sharing".  Then they will get the sharing context of the caller.  Since the "inherited sharing" option has been added, it's considered good programming to always include a sharing option in every class declaration and never declare a class without one of the sharing options.
